# Is Jesus the Creator?

Tags: creation, trinity, christology

The following verses clearly credit Jesus Christ with “Creation.” **How do Christians view the role of Christ in Creation?**

*Ephesians 3:9:*

> And to make all [men] see what [is] the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of the world hath been hid in God, who **created all things by Jesus Christ**:

John 1:1-14:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. The same was in the beginning with God. **All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made**…and the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth.

Colossians 1:16:

> For **by him (Jesus Christ) were all things created**, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether [they be] thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him

Comment: The question presumes that Jesus and the Father are one. IIRC, the answer is more complex than that, because the Son and the Father are joined in a hypostatic union, as it is believed in the Orthodox tradition. You may be looking for the relationship between Jesus and the Son of God.

Comment: @Anonymous: Actually, AFAIK, the hypostatic union describes the union of Christ's divine and human natures, not his union with the Father. Here's a quick [reference](http://www.desiringgod.org/blog/posts/what-is-the-hypostatic-union) from a site I like to use that might help. As far as how the Father and Son are related, the way the Council of Constantinople said it in 381 CE was, the Father, Son, and Spirit are "one *ousia*" and "thee *hypostases*." The doctrine of the Trinity can be really confusing, IMHO.

Comment: related - [Is there a hierarchy in the Trinity?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2881/69)

Comment: I think this can qualify as an overview type question. There aren't too many views and they can all be explained in a concise answer.

Answer (score 7):

For Christians that are creationists, and that accept the [doctrine of the Trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-is-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity), yes.

From [CARM.org](http://carm.org/jesus-god), which believes and advocates both doctrines.  The idea that Jesus is Creator is one of the arguments to support that Jesus is God.

<sup>* CARM is not alone in this belief, but I decided to link to only one reference.</sup>

[image]

---

To anyone who rejects the idea of Creationism altogether, or to anyone or any group that doesn't believe that Jesus is God, the answer would be "no".

Comment: How did you get that image? It looks nice.

Comment: @Anonymous print screen and paste into any image editor, crop and save, then upload.

Comment: @DavidStratton If you are using **Windows 7** there is a tool called **Snipping Tool**, better than old fashioned print screen.

Comment: @David, So what is your answer to: How do Christians view the role of Christ in Creation?

Comment: It's that some believe He is the Creator, and some don't.  There's not universal agreement.  Of course, there is one absolute Truth, but this site isn't about which view is correct, just what the various views are.  With that constraint, "some think this, some think that" is the best posible allowale answer because quite frankly, the various groups within Christianity agree on little.  That's why people are always asking others to narow down a question to a denominational scope, to try to get at less vague answers.

Comment: @DavidStratton The Bible says it is so and that is good enough for me, my question is "how is it so"?

Comment: @DavidStratton Perhaps Jesus is the "Divine Doer"of the omniscient "will" of God the Father?

Comment: @Rick: What do you mean, "How is it so?" Do you want us to describe how Jesus created? Or, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I guess I don't know.. All I get from the text is he said "Let there be" and there was.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Jesus is the logos the “word” in the gospel of John.  We understand the difference between a promise made and a promise fulfilled, the “word” and the “work”.  The “word” that became flesh is Jesus Christ. The “will” of the “work” is God the Father.

Comment: Perhaps Christ's roll in Creation is essentially the same?

Comment: `To anyone who rejects the idea of Creationism ... the answer would be "no"` I suppose that depends on how you define 'Creationism'.  I don't identify as a Creationist; more a Theological Evolutionist; but I believe that Jesus was the creator.

Comment: A "creationist" strictly means someone who believes the world was created by God, which pretty much includes all Christians. But it is usually used these days to mean "one who believes in a young earth" which is a minority of Christians. If you meant the first, then saying "anyone who is a creationist" is redundant. if you mean the second then it's not true, even non-(young earth)- creationists believe Jesus was the creator.

Answer (score 3):

> **[Isaiah 48:12-13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2048:12-13&version=KJV)** (KJV)
>   <sup>12</sup>  Hearken unto me, O Jacob and Israel, my called; I am he; I am the first, I also am the last.

(*What is Jesus called in [Revelation](http://biblehub.com/revelation/22-13.htm)? Alpha and Omega...*)

> <sup>13</sup>  Mine hand also hath laid the foundation of the earth, and my right hand hath spanned the heavens: when I call unto them, they stand up together.

The above shows that the Bible teaches Jesus Christ to be the Creator. And Christians believe the propositions of the Bible to be true. Thus Christians believe that Jesus "laid the foundation of the earth" etc.

But Christians, having established that Jesus is God the Son, the 2nd person of the Trinity and the Word of God, would thus see Christ as that Word which proceeded from the Father's mouth when He (the Father) spoke at creation. Thus Christ was the energizing Word that created all things for the Father.
We are not to imagine that the Father has vocal cords (He is a Spirit). His "speaking' is an anthropomorphic term. The Word that He spoke, being that same Word which was in the beginning with God and was God (John 1). This shows us a glimpse of how tightly knit the Persons of the Trinity are. The Son is the very Word of the Father, Who brings all things into existence for the Father and the Holy Spirit is His breath. Amazing imagery to meditate upon!

As a short reference to the above thought, please hear [Calvin](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/calvin/institutes.iii.xiv.html) :"Since at the very moment when God said, "Let there be light," The energy of the Word was immediately exerted......"

Comment: So what is your answer to: How do Christians view the role of Christ in Creation?

Comment: Sorry...Good point. See last paragraph in answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Is Jesus the Creator?**
No. As we usually see when this question is asked in a variety of ways, the same verses are usually referred to - however they are usually misapplied or misunderstood.

Let's examine the ones used by OP. We'll get to *Jesus' role in creation* shortly.

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. The same was in the beginning with God. All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made…and the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth. John 1:1-14

John is not talking about Jesus here. The logos is *not yet Jesus* because Jesus was not yet born. While that may sound odd, it is true if we allow scripture to speak freely unburdened by traditional interpretations. Jesus was born ~4BC so could not possibly be 'in the beginning' or the Creator.

> For by him (Jesus Christ) were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him. Col 1:16

Notice the easy give away if we are looking to read the text or believe what we are told it says. "in heaven" and "in (or on) earth" This cannot be talking about a Genesis creation -

> In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth Gen 1:1

God doesn't inspire the wrong words, clumsy words or confusing words. Colossians' context is of the new creation and the church. Keep reading

> all things have been created **through** Him and **for** Him

Not BY him! Jesus will **come** to have first place in everything. Why? Because he didn't have first place before he was born in anything except as the key to God's plan of salvation for all men.

> He is before all things, and in Him all things hold together. 18 He is also the head of the body, the church; and He is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead, so that He Himself will come to have first place in everything.

That's why he said to the Jews - 'before Abraham was, I am'. Not because he was God, but because *God had planned* for him to come "in these last days" (Heb 1:1) well before Abraham existed.

**Jesus' role in God's plan was **far more important** than Abraham's.**

> and to enlighten all people as to what the plan of the mystery is which for ages has been hidden in God, who created all things Eph 3:9

Note: "through Jesus Christ" in OP quote is an addition in the KJV and a couple others. So God created, we know from many places that Jesus isn't God - he is the image and form of God, but Jesus is not the Creator of Genesis. This understanding can only be obtained by inference, speculation, addition and mis-reading the word God has provided. Paul and Jesus have been quite clear about who God is and who Jesus is. Creation is not attributed to Jesus - he wasn't born yet. But all things realise their eternal destiny, just as God planed, **through Jesus**.

> Now this is eternal life: that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you have sent. John 17:3

> yet for us there is but one God, the Father, from whom all things came and for whom we live; and there is but one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom all things came and through whom we live. 1 Cor 8:6

Comment: The question is tagged trinity; this answer does not involve the trinity. Please update to match that framework

Answer (score 1):

The [Catechism of the Council of Trent](http://archive.org/stream/thecatechismofth00donouoft/thecatechismofth00donouoft_djvu.txt) teaches that Creation is the common work of the Three Divine Persons

> Let thus much suffice for the explanation of the first article of
>   Creation, the Creed : it may not, however, be unnecessary to add that
>   the creation is the common work of the three Persons of the Holy
>   Persons, and undivided Trinity of the Father, whom, according to the
>   doctrine of the Apostles, we here declare to be " Creator of heaven
>   and earth ;" of the Son, of whom the Scripture says, " all things were
>   made by him ;" and of the Holy Ghost, of whom it is written, "The
>   Spirit of God moved over the waters:" and again, " By the word of the
>   Lord the heavens were established and all the power of them by the
>   Spirit of his mouth."

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is the word of god that became flesh.

The words of man are flimsy, men can lie and change their positions.

The will and word of god never change, and as such the words that he speaks ring true and are consistent throughout time.

Because he has had all knowledge and all things are known until him, he does not "grow" as men do: he has made all things from the beginning.

As such, Christ Jesus is the word.

In the beginning was the word, and the word was with god and the word was god.

This is because GOD CANNOT LIE! he can only speak of himself, that in which means that when he speaks, he speaks himself! Every word that he utters IS the ESSENCE OF GOD!

And out of the abundance of the heart, the mouth speaks, so Jesus has been there since the beginning and even before the world began.

Comment: Needs work to clarify how it is answering the question of how Christ was involved in the creation (beyond establishing Christ's eternality and Divine knowledge). It is also wordy (for its content) and argumentative in tone (reading more like street evangelism than an academic or professional argument). (Referencing you Bible quotes would also help.) Unfortunately [our guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1920) (also [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1898/3331) and [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1898)) are not yet well-developed.